# How to predict by hand in R using splines regression?

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, interpretation, splines

The R package `splines` allows one to fit a non linear model using splines. For instance,

```
require(stats); require(graphics)
bs(women$height, df = 5)
summary(fm1 <- lm(weight ~ bs(height, df = 5), data = women))

## example of safe prediction
plot(women, xlab = "Height (in)", ylab = "Weight (lb)")
ht <- seq(57, 73, length.out = 200)
lines(ht, predict(fm1, data.frame(height = ht)))
```

This produces the following estimates

```
Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ bs(height, df = 5), data = women)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.31764 -0.13441  0.03922  0.11096  0.35086 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         114.8799     0.2167 530.146  < 2e-16 ***
bs(height, df = 5)1   3.4657     0.4595   7.543 3.53e-05 ***
bs(height, df = 5)2  13.0300     0.3965  32.860 1.10e-10 ***
bs(height, df = 5)3  27.6161     0.4571  60.415 4.70e-13 ***
bs(height, df = 5)4  40.8481     0.3866 105.669 3.09e-15 ***
bs(height, df = 5)5  49.1296     0.3090 158.979  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2276 on 9 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9999,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9998 
F-statistic: 1.298e+04 on 5 and 9 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

If I want to predict using these estimates, what should I put in the predictive model?

$$\hat{y} =  \hat{\beta}^T \textbf{(?)}.$$

I know that I can obtain the predictions using the command `predict`, but I want to understand what is this command doing. Is it $\textbf{(?)} =  bs(x, df = 5)$?

Comment: Did you try model.matrix() applied to your model? That should give you what you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per my comment, once you fit your model, you can extract the values of the predictors included in the model using the **model.matrix()** function:

```
require(stats) 
require(splines)
require(graphics)

fm1 <- lm(weight ~ bs(height, df = 5), data = women)

summary(fm1)

model.matrix(fm1)
```

The R output produced by **model.matrix()** for your model is as follows:

```
> model.matrix(fm1)
   (Intercept) bs(height, df = 5)1 bs(height, df = 5)2 bs(height, df = 5)3 bs(height, df = 5)4 bs(height, df = 5)5
1            1        0.000000e+00         0.000000000         0.000000000        0.000000e+00         0.000000000
2            1        4.534439e-01         0.059857872         0.001639942        0.000000e+00         0.000000000
3            1        5.969388e-01         0.203352770         0.013119534        0.000000e+00         0.000000000
4            1        5.338010e-01         0.376366618         0.044278426        0.000000e+00         0.000000000
5            1        3.673469e-01         0.524781341         0.104956268        0.000000e+00         0.000000000
6            1        2.001640e-01         0.595025510         0.204719388        9.110787e-05         0.000000000
7            1        9.110787e-02         0.566326531         0.336734694        5.830904e-03         0.000000000
8            1        3.125000e-02         0.468750000         0.468750000        3.125000e-02         0.000000000
9            1        5.830904e-03         0.336734694         0.566326531        9.110787e-02         0.000000000
10           1        9.110787e-05         0.204719388         0.595025510        2.001640e-01         0.000000000
11           1        0.000000e+00         0.104956268         0.524781341        3.673469e-01         0.002915452
12           1        0.000000e+00         0.044278426         0.376366618        5.338010e-01         0.045553936
13           1        0.000000e+00         0.013119534         0.203352770        5.969388e-01         0.186588921
14           1        0.000000e+00         0.001639942         0.059857872        4.534439e-01         0.485058309
15           1        0.000000e+00         0.000000000         0.000000000        0.000000e+00         1.000000000
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

According to this output, the weight can be predicted from height via a linear combination of basis functions as follows:

\begin{align*}
weight = \beta_0 + \beta_1*bs(height, df = 5)1 + \beta_2*bs(height, df = 5)2 + \\ \beta_3*bs(height, df = 5)3 + \beta_4* bs(height, df = 5)4 + \\ \beta_5 * bs(height, df = 5)5
\end{align*}

However, since the regression coefficients $\beta_0$ through $\beta_5$ are unknown, you will need to replace them with their estimated values $b0$ through $b5$ reported in the model summary when computing the predicted weight.  For example, from summary(fm1), you will find that $b0 = 114.8799$, $b1 = 3.4657$, etc.

You can therefore predict weight as a function of height - for all the heights observed in the data - using the R command, which is R's translation of the above equation):

```
pred <- model.matrix(fm1) %*% coef(fm1)
```

The predicted weights are as follows:

```
> pred
       [,1]
1  114.8799
2  117.2767
3  119.9608
4  122.8568
5  125.8895
6  128.9841
7  132.1124
8  135.3176
9  138.6491
10 142.1564
11 145.8886
12 149.8935
13 154.2176
14 158.9074
15 164.0095
```

Finally, you can plot these predicted weights and compare them against your "safe" predictions to see they look identical:

```
plot(women, xlab = "Height (in)", ylab = "Weight (lb)")

ht <- seq(57, 73, length.out = 200)

lines(ht, predict(fm1, data.frame(height = ht)), lwd=3, col="grey")

lines(women$height, pred, col = "magenta", lty=2, lwd = 2)

legend("topleft", c("Safe prediction","model.matrix() prediction"), 
       lty=c(1,2), lwd=c(3,2), col=c("grey","magenta"))
```

[image]

You can plot the basis functions used in the approximation of the effect of height on weight with these commands:

```
matplot(women$height, model.matrix(fm1)[,-1], type='l', 
       col=rainbow(5), lwd=2)
legend("top", legend = dimnames(model.matrix(fm1))[[2]][-1], 
       col=rainbow(5), lty=1:5, bty="n", lwd=2)
```

The resulting plot is shown below.  From this plot, if you want to predict weight for a height of 70 inches, say, you would evaluate each of the 5 basis functions at 70 inches and then multiply the results with the corresponding basis function coefficients reported by R and add the estimated intercept on top of it:

\begin{align*}
weight = b_0 + b_1*bs(height = 70, df = 5)1 + b_2*bs(height = 70, df = 5)2 + \\ b_3*bs(height = 70, df = 5)3 + b_4* bs(height = 70, df = 5)4 + \\  b_5 * bs(height = 70, df = 5)5
\end{align*}

Here, the $b$'s are used to denote the estimated values of the $\beta$'s.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, @Splinter! 